# bash script run to send process to background

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Hi Im making a script to do some rsync process, for the rsync process, Sys admin has created the script, when it run it is asking select options, so i want to create a script to pass that argument from script and run it from cron.

list of directories to rsync take from file.

```
filelist=$(cat filelist.txt)

for i in filelist;do
    echo -e "3\nY" | ./rsync.sh $i
```

#This will create a rsync log file
 so i check the some value of  log file and if it is empty i moving to the second file. if the file is not empty, i have to start rsync process as below that will take more that 2 hours.

```
if [ a != 0 ];then 
      echo -e "3\nN" | ./rsync.sh $i
```

above rsync process need to send to the background and take next file to loop. i check with the screen command, but screen is not working with server. also i need to get the duration that take to run process and passing to the log, when i use the time command i am unable to pass the echo variable. Also need to send this to background and take next file. appreciate any suggestions to success this task.

Question
1. How to send  argument with Time command 
echo -e "3\nY" | time ./rsync.sh $i
above one not working

2. how to send this to background and take next file to rsync while running previous rsync process.

Full Code

```
#!/bin/bash
filelist=$(cat filelist.txt)
Lpath=/opt/sas/sas_control/scripts/Logs/rsync_logs
date=$(date +"%m-%d-%Y")
timelog="time_result/rsync_time.log-$date"

for i in $filelist;do
        #echo $i
        b_i=$(basename $i)
        echo $b_i
        echo -e "3\nY" | ./rsync.sh $i
        f=$(cat $Lpath/$(ls -tr $Lpath| grep rsync-dry-run-$b_i | tail -1) | grep 'transferred:' | cut -d':' -f2)
        echo $f
        if [ $f != 0 ]; then
                #date=$(date +"%D : %r")
                start_time=`date +%s`
                echo "$b_i-start:$start_time" >> $timelog
                #time ./rsync.sh $i < echo -e "3\nY" 2> "./time_result/$b_i-$date" &
                time { echo -e "3\nY" | ./rsync.sh $i; } 2> "./time_result/$b_i-$date"
                end_time=`date +%s`
                s_time=$(cat $timelog|grep "$b_i-start" |cut -d ':' -f2)
                duration=$(($end_time-$s_time))
                echo "$b_i duration:$duration" >> $timelog

        fi

done
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How to send it to background and how to use time command with passing variable from echo

Answer (score 0):

If you want to time something, you can use:

```
time sleep 3
```

If you want to time two things, you can do a compound statement like this (note semicolon after second `sleep`):

```
time { sleep 3; sleep 4; }
```

So, you can do this to time your `echo` (which will take no time at all) and your `rsync`:

```
time { echo "something" | rsync something ; }
```

If you want to do that in the background:

```
time { echo "something" | rsync something ; } &
```

Full Code

```
#!/bin/bash
filelist=$(cat filelist.txt)
Lpath=/opt/sas/sas_control/scripts/Logs/rsync_logs
date=$(date +"%m-%d-%Y")
timelog="time_result/rsync_time.log-$date"

for i in $filelist;do
        #echo $i
        b_i=$(basename $i)
        echo $b_i
        echo -e "3\nY" | ./rsync.sh $i
        f=$(cat $Lpath/$(ls -tr $Lpath| grep rsync-dry-run-$b_i | tail -1) | grep 'transferred:' | cut -d':' -f2)
        echo $f
        if [ $f != 0 ]; then
                #date=$(date +"%D : %r")
                start_time=`date +%s`
                echo "$b_i-start:$start_time" >> $timelog
                #time ./rsync.sh $i < echo -e "3\nY" 2> "./time_result/$b_i-$date" &
                time { echo -e "3\nY" | ./rsync.sh $i; } 2> "./time_result/$b_i-$date"
                end_time=`date +%s`
                s_time=$(cat $timelog|grep "$b_i-start" |cut -d ':' -f2)
                duration=$(($end_time-$s_time))
                echo "$b_i duration:$duration" >> $timelog

        fi

done
```

Comment: this is working but I cant get the time out put to my log file , Also this is not take next file once i send this to Background

time { echo -e "3\nY" | ./rsync.sh $i; } > "./time_result/$b_i-$date"

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear, but I'll try:

(1) If I understand you correctly, you want to time the `rsync`.

My first attempt would be to use `echo xxxx | time rsycnc`. On my `bash`, this was however broken (or not supposed to work?). I'm normally using Zsh instead of bash, and on zsht, this indeed runs fine.

If it is important for you to use bash, an alternative (since the time for the `echo` can likely be neglected) would be to time the whole pipe, i.e. `time (echo xxxx | time rsync)`, or even simpler `time rsync <(echo xxxx)`

(2) To send a process to the background, add an `&` to the line.  However, the *time* command produces of course output (that's it purpose), and you don't want to receive output from a program in background. The solution is to redirect the output:

```
(time rsync <(echo xxxx) >output.txt 2>error.txt) &
```

Comment: No friend, it is not working, it is giving no directory found error.

Comment: There is no directory mentioned in the example I gave, so this error is not related to the topic dicussed (timing a command and starting a background process). Show me a listing of the actual code, and the exact error message. ... Having said this, I hope that you didn't copy my code **literally**, but adapted it to your concrete needs, did you????

Comment: Looking at the full code, I notice: (1) You don't start any background process (I just mention this for completeness). (2) You don't indicate, which line in the code gives *directory not found* (I **guess** it is the line with the *rsync.sh* command). (3) You did not indicate, **which** directory is not found (there are two directories mentioned in this line, plus the error could also come from inside the rsync.sh scripts). Without this information, it is hard to give any advice ...